# Página com login e senha

Tags: php

Eu criei um sistema de login e senha bem simples mesmo, porém quando eu jogo eles para o *FTP*, com a senha e login que eu informo, não entra, fica na página de login.

```
<?php
// Definimos o nome de usuário e senha de acesso
$usuario = "fmc";
$senha = "lorga";

// Criamos uma função que exibirá uma mensagem de erro caso os dados estejam errados
function erro(){
    // Definindo Cabeçalhos
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Administracao"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    // Mensagem que será exibida
    echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Área Restrita Você Não Tem Permissão, estamos lhe redirecionando para a página de solicitação de senha');window.location.href='solicitacao.php'</script>";
    // Pára o carregamento da página
    exit;
}

// Se as informações não foram setadas
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) or !isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])) {
    erro();
} 
// Se as informações foram setadas
else {
    // Se os dados informados forem diferentes dos definidos
    if ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] != $usuario or $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] != $senha) {
        erro();
    }
}


require_once("includes/header.php");


?>
```

No localhost funciona normalmente, porém, no servidor em si não funciona.

Comment: As versões do PHP no localhost e no server são iguais? Sabe se as configurações do teu php.ini são iguais as do server?

Comment: Não sei te dizer Saul. Vou verificar e te falo.

Comment: Algumas sugestões para identificar o problema: Verifique sua versão do *PHP* e compare com a versão de produção; Verifique o *log* de erros do apache; Utilize o `var_dump()` para "debugar" o código no servidor

Comment: Aonde a variável `$_SESSION` é inicializada? Mesmo sendo simples, não quer ter/aprender um código mais seguro para login?

Comment: Sim, porém, é apenas para resguardas informações.